# The typing module: built-in support for on-demand type checking?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this code:

```
from typing import Tuple
t = Tuple[str, int]
x = ('a', 1)
y = ('b', 'c')
assert f(x, t)
assert not f(y, t)
```

Is there a built-in function that does on-demand type checking against `typing` types, that behaves equivalent to the function `f` above?  I've explored [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) but didn't find what seems like an obvious feature, so maybe I just missed it?

---

Further inspection:

`Tuple[str, int].__tuple_params__` is `(str, int)`
`List[int].__args__` is `(int,)`
`Dict[str, int].__args__` is `(str, int)`

Comment: Did you mean 'automatic'?